# Force exact match for `gem list`

Tags: rubygems

`gem list rails` used to match everything that *began* with "rails" (and [the documentation still claims it works that way](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_list)) but at some point it started matching everything that *includes* rails anywhere in the name.  This can get ridiculous, as there are (at the moment I write this, but I'm sure it goes up practically by the hour) 2,764 items that match "rails":

```
gem list rails --remote | wc -l
2764
```

Can Rubygems be made to only return exact matches by default?  I don't see any [commandline switches that force an exact match](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_list).  Perhaps a setting in `~/.gemrc`?

Obviously I can do this by piping the output to other utilities, but that's kind of a pain to do every time you just want to (e.g.) check the latest version of a gem, and it's a lot slower, and forces you to stop and think about a detail that (IMO) is a distraction from whatever problem you're working on.

```
gem list rails --remote | grep '^rails '
```

Is there a good way to make this the default?

Answer (score 8):

You are basically entering a regex on the command line, so

```
gem list -r ^rails$
```

does an exact search without piping. I'm using rubygems 2.0.6 and 2.4.5 and it worked on both versions.

I couldn't find anything to put in .gemrc, though. You could easily set up a wrapper shell script for your most common case.

Comment: I don't think an alias could work to change the behavior of `gem list -r`, since it involves multiple tokens, unless you mean an alias with a new made-up command, or unless you know some alias wizardry that I'm not familiar with (but which I'd be very interested in learning!).

Comment: Oh, you're right about that I think, since I don't think you can get the dollar sign in there. You might be able to do it with a shell script wrapper for your most common use case. Answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for gems starting with "rails" you can use a search string starting with '^':

```
gem list ^rails+ --remote
```

I've tried `list` with version 1.8.24 of rubygems, where the behaviour is as described in the documentation, but for rubygems 2.2.1 you'll have to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems they added an option in version 2.7.3 or thereabouts. I don't have it in 2.5.1.

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-list

```
-e, -​-exact - Name of gem(s) to query on matches the provided STRING
```

If you are on Windows, you have to use quotes for the REGEX or else it won't work.

```
gem list "^pg$" --remote --all
```